# Delete values from multi value user profile property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user-profile-service

How can I remove a property value from a user profile multi valued property.

I have a custom multi valued(string) property where I can add items.But does anyone know if how to remove any value matching my criteria from that property.

Thanks.

[Please note : I am only willing to delete property value not the property/any code snippet will be helpful]

Comment: Is it associated with an MMS term set?

Comment: No..Its a cutom property of multi value

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried? It should be no different from using fields in a SharePoint List.